# Font Type of Digital Research Inc

Tags: font-identification

Could anyone tell the font type that is used for Digital Research Inc. logo ? I tried online font services in order to find the type but they could not separate the E and A in the word RESEARCH.

[image]

Best Regards

Comment: You don't need to separate E and A, there are already other samples of these letters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Friz Quadrata](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/friz-quadrata/) a glyphic roman typeface, via myfonts.com

[image]